# AJAX request to python bottle giving cross domain error

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cross-domain, bottle

I'm making an AJAX call from my jboss local server to python bottle server but I'm getting following error.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But when I put that URL directly in the browser I get proper response.

I've written the decorator for it as below

```
def enable_cors(fn):
def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
    # set CORS headers
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'

    if request.method != 'OPTIONS':
        # actual request; reply with the actual response
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

return _enable_cors
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: try adding request.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true') it solved my problem

Comment: also;         request.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-prototype-version,x-requested-with')